# Code that starts with a variable named "hello" gets dropped

Tags: bug, automatic-edits

Someone [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248205/how-would-i-make-an-if-statement-with-a-dictionary-list/20248361#20248361) that started with a code sample, and the sample began by assigning a variable named `hello`. The input filtering removed that line. I tried to do the same thing [in my reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20248361/5987) and not only did it consistently remove the line it wrecked the format of the rest of the code sample.

If anyone knows the proper tags to add to this question, please do so.

Comment: Looks like you're getting hit by the automatic tagline remover.

Comment: The better thing to do is to start your post with an explanation of your code, rather than just posting code.

Comment: @gunr2171 Even if that's true, the user should probably be alerted that their first line of code was automatically deleted. Most users aren't going to know that they shouldn't start with a code block iff the code block begins with "hello".

Comment: Ah! Now that explains why there was the stray `hi']` in the post, that I removed. It was rather strange, that first line.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this happened to the OP as well, see the [first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20248205/1).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I assumed it had based on a comment under the question.

Comment: @gunr2171, is there a rule that the explanation must come before the code rather than after it?

Comment: @MarkRansom, there is no _rule_, I would just find it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding an empty comment block before your code. The problem is that we have a filter set in place that automatically removes "Hello", "Thanks", etc. lines from the post when you save.

As others have said in the comments though, you should add an explanation of the code.

Comment: Thanks, but that's just a hack for this particular post. I started the question hoping the filter could become more finely tuned for everyone.

Comment: @Mark IMHO, the filter is crap. It doesn't seem to work anymore. Unless I can see done stats on its success, I'm against it.

Comment: I guess I can't argue with that. I always thought Jeff's rationale was a little questionable.